# How to check the type of action received from a broadcast receiver in android?

Tags: android

I am currently working on Broadcast receivers in android and i don't know how to check the type of action called in the Broad Cast receiver. Below is my manifest file and the java file:

android manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:typeface="serif">
    <receiver android:name=".Main2Activity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Java File:

```
package com.example.ashis.assignment1;

public class Main2Activity extends BroadcastReceiver {

    /*
     * @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     * super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     * setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2); }
     */

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Wallpaper has been changed......", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to check the type of action that is described in the manifest file in my `Main2Activity.java` file?

Answer (score 4):

Since below code is the Receiver you are adding in Manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".Main2Activity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

You can use `intent.getAction()` to check what type of Action is happened like :

```
public class Main2Activity extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String message = "";
    switch (intent.getAction()) {
        case Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED:
            message = "Power Connected";
            break;
        case Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED:
            message = "Power Disconnected";
            break;

    }
    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your onReceive() method

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
String action=intent.getAction();
 if(action.equals("android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED")){

   Toast.makeText(context,"action",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as this:

```
String action = intent.getAction();
```

Comment: But what about who took that action? like which system service, app, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<receiver android:name=".PowerStatusReceiver ">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Then Register recievers Like this in `onCreate` of `activity`

```
// register our power status receivers

    IntentFilter powerConnectedFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED);
    registerReceiver(PowerStatusReceiver , powerConnectedFilter);

    IntentFilter powerDisconnectedFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED);
    registerReceiver(PowerStatusReceiver , powerDisconnectedFilter);
```

Define our BroadcastReceiver and embed the BATTERY_STATUS request within it

```
BroadcastReceiver PowerStatusReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);

        // Are we charging / charged?
        int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
        isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                     status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;
    }
};
```

Comment: your answer is not related to question. update your answer.

Comment: his code is not working ,because he doesnt know how to do that, my answer is complete , not your concern!!

Comment: When you specify Android's inbuild Intent Filter Action, no need to register receiver anywhere, Android will do it for you.

Comment: yeah , or we can specify it by Activity$class name in manifest